# Japanese military term which in English connoted the overrunning of an enemy's defensive position by sheer numbers

Tags: single-word-requests

Many years ago while perusing one of Barnhart's dictionaries of new English, I came across a two-word (as I remember) Japanese military term which in English connoted the overrunning of an enemy's defensive position by sheer numbers.  That is: the assumed Japanese tactic would be to send 1000 men against a machine gun nest that only had 900 bullets, or something like that.

Possible usage, depending on what part of speech it turns out to be:

> The enemy ________ our position
>   *or*
>   The enemy performed a ________ against us.

Comment: The "1000 men vs 900 bullets" implies a *brute force* tactic applying *overwhelming manpower* to compensate for *inferior firepower*.

Comment: The enemy *overran* your position.

Comment: The enemy **swarmed** our position?

Answer (score 15):

Through [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banzai_charge), you will find a few terms, namely **Tennōheika Banzai**, **banzai charge** and the **human wave attack**.

There is also the common term *swarming*.

Comment: Although not common in everyday use (which is why this is a comment, not an answer), in gaming communities, this is sometimes referred to as "zerging" the enemy.  It usually has implied connotations of an attack too quick to efficiently respond to.  (The term comes from the Zerg race in Starcraft, which tended to use numerous cheap units to overrun superior enemy positions.)

Comment: TY for the response: while that is not the exact one that I recall from Barnhart, it is very useful input which I will use.

Comment: @Ghotir Also known as a Zerg rush.

Comment: "[Tennōheika Banzai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_thousand_years)" was a war cry used by Japanese soldiers in WWII, often _during_ human wave attacks (hence "banzai charge" in English), but unlike "banzai charge" I don't think it will be understood as referring specifically to this type of attack.  I would use "human wave attack" or "swarm attack" unless I was writing specifically about the Pacific theater of WWII.

Comment: The term as I've usually heard it is *zerg rush*. @Ghotir

Comment: TY for the locution: I am always interested in such neologism, but - in this case, was attempting to remember a Barnhart-referenced, specific Japanese two-word term which did not use "banzai."